# How do I play a real media '.rm' file

Tags: multimedia, vlc, video-player

No player seems to support the Real Media codecs I need. I have even tried VLC and movie player, both of which failed.

Answer (score 4):

You may be in the need to install Restricted Extras on your system. You can do it by dropping `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras` in a terminal

Additionally, information provided in [**this page**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats) can be useful, specially this which refers to [Real Media](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RealPlayerInstallationMethods), posted here for your convenience.

> ***Introduction***
>
> RealPlayer is a media player originally developed by RealNetworks in
>   1995. It supports a number of audio and video codecs such as
>   realaudio, realvideo, mp3, ogg vorbis and theora, h263, and AAC.
>   RealPlayer for Linux is based on the open-source Helix Player which
>   can be found at the Helix Community Website.
>
> Please Note: RealPlayer is proprietary software, is not supported by
>   the Ubuntu community, and is not available from the official Ubuntu
>   repositories. It is located in the non-free section of third-party
>   repositories which the user must specifically enable.

Which lead us to the possibility of the installation (alternatively, of course), of the Real Media Player for Linux, which seems to be discontinued but you can find older versions in the "[Helix and RealPlayer Archive](https://player.helixcommunity.org/2005/downloads/)"

However, the installation of the sole codec should do the trick. I suggest you  to try the restricted extras in first instance and to try again the .rm playback using your favorite media player.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

> MPlayer plays most MPEG, VOB, AVI, Ogg/OGM, VIVO, ASF/WMA/WMV,
>   QT/MOV/MP4, FLI, ***RM***, NuppelVideo, yuv4mpeg, FILM, RoQ, PVA files,
>   supported by many native, XAnim, RealPlayer, and Win32 DLL codecs. It
>   can also play VideoCD, SVCD, DVD, 3ivx, RealMedia, and DivX movies.

[SMPlayer](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/smplayer) (GUI for MPlayer)

Comment: `ubuntu-restricted-extras` is a bit stupid. It even downloads some microsoft fonts and ask me to agree to their eula which i will never do. Need a better option

Comment: The additional page mentioned is tooooo outdated

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu restricted (install as said above or in Synaptic or Ubuntu Software Center) is a must as far as I am concerned. Many other problems may be solved this way. It worked for me and didn't have to agree to anything like eula etc. Nothing wrong having the microsoft fonts. As far as a better option is concerned, a "better" one has to be a possible one. This one works. SMPLAYER is a must too. Anyway, the fact that VLC didn't do the trick in the fist place might point to a special problem with the file.

But finally you might want to try Real Player for linux ([here](http://uk.real.com/realplayer/other-versions))

Comment: Answer or comment?