# How do I install Realplayer?

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install RealPlayer?

Does anyone know how I can successfully achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

### History

[Medibuntu](http://www.medibuntu.org/) was an external repository which held packages for non-free software such as RealPlayer.

However, in 2013, this repository was taken offline and has ceased.

- [The Medibuntu Project has come to an end - what do I do now?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/356794/the-medibuntu-project-has-come-to-an-end-what-do-i-do-now)

Development of RealPlayer from the original software house has [ceased](https://player.helixcommunity.org/2007/releases/RealPlayer/ReleaseNotes.html).  The source was passed to the Helix Community. It appears from the [Helix CVS](https://helixcommunity.org/viewcvs/player/) repository, no significant linux updates have been made for some considerable amount of time.

Thus, RealPlayer is in reality a self compile and install method.  The helix community has some [notes](https://community.helixcommunity.org/Developers/quick_start/linux) how to achieve this.

PPA's for this software may exist - but I've not been able to find any for recent supported versions of Ubuntu.

### Alternatives

There are other linux media clients that cover the stream-types and functionality that the old RealPlayer and Helix-Players did.

- [What media (music and video) players are there?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42532/what-media-players-are-there)
- [How do I play a real media '.rm' file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59585/how-do-i-play-a-real-media-rm-file)

XMBC is also a good media system that covers some of real-player's streaming capabilities

- [How do I install XBMC?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2652/how-do-i-install-xbmc)